# Reason to close "how to" question?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

[This question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5636/775) looks off topic to me. The problem is, I can't quite figure out what to put as the closure reason. It seems to me that "how do I do things with this tool that *just happens to be* open source" questions are off topic, but I can't quite articulate why it should be closed. So...

1. Should it be put on hold?
2. Why?

Comment: I think the key word is version maintained that throws me off. There's something about it that feels open source relevant, but the entire context of the question is just really different. My initial inclination would be that it's on-topic, but I feel that it's also something we haven't really dived into before. Looking forward to discussion here

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way I can write blogs on medium but still have those version maintained on github.

There's a tiny chance that this could be asking about the licensing of the Medium site and whether it would allow cross posting, but...

> Or write them on Jekyll github pages and have them post to medium?

This shows it's a technical question, and therefore off-topic.

Comment: Okay, but how would you word that closure reason? That's what I'm struggling with. (Also, I'm thinking there will be a follow up requesting a change to the pre-worded reasons.)

Comment: @RubberDuck Well as it's effectively asking for an automated cross site posting system/service/product I think the current close reason is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Over on [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), we not uncommonly get what sounds like a very similar situation around graphical editing tools (Photoshop etc): "Photoshop is used by photographers, therefore my question about Photoshop is on-topic".

How we deal with this is exactly how you'd expect: if the question is actually about photography (e.g. "How do I use Photoshop to remove a blemish from a photo?"), it's on-topic. If it's not about photography (e.g. "How do I use Photoshop to draw a picture of an elephant?"), we close it with a custom close reason phrased something like "Questions about Photoshop are on-topic only if they have a clear photographic application. Please edit your question to include the photographic context" and/or pointing them to an appropriate site. I'd imagine something similar could work here:

> Questions about open source software are on-topic only if they relate to the open source aspects of the software, as opposed to using the software. Such questions can potentially be asked at [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).